# Bootstrap 3 carousel not going to next or previous slide manually. Automatic sliding function works perfectly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Here is my code. I don't think anything is wrong with it. It also scrolls up to the top of the carousel when I click next.

It should be really basic... but I just cannot figure it out.

It seems to change slides perfectly on its own, but when I click next or previous it goes to slide 2. If I click next or previous again, it still goes to slide 2.

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!--             Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

<!--             Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

                <div class="item active slide-ethernet">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        Networking.
                    </div>
                </div>

                   <div class="item slide-pcb">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                       Repair.
                    </div>
                    </div>


                <div class="item slide-code">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        Web.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

<!--             Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happen when you use the same id more than one time in the page ... do you have a fiddle where it not works ?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what that means, so I would be inclined to say no. I have yet to master webdesign but I am working towards it!

Comment: a fiddle is a online functional version of your code, you people on stackoverflow usually put their pieces of code on http://jsfiddle.net/ so people can change stuff and show you what is wrong.

Comment: Oh sorry, I am new to the community and have never used that before. This is just a slightly altered code pulled right from boot-straps website.

Comment: So if you can post a little example of how you use the bootstrap caroussel on your page, i will be happy to helps you find what's wrong. From my expérience, when i used multiple carousel on the same page, i got exactly the same error behaviour that you described if i forget the unicity of the id